# Did the average Linux Symposium T-Shirt size increase from 1999 to 2008?

Tags: clothing

A [widely circulated image](http://techcrunch.com/2008/09/09/are-linux-programmers-getting-too-fat/) claims:

[image]

> TechCrunch50 company FitBit (which demoed its health activity monitoring device live as well) put up this slide to underscore its point that obesity is a growing problem, particularly in the geek world. The slide shows how the distribution of T-shirt sizes at the Linux Symposium has shifted towards the XL and XXL side of the scale.

Is it true that wider T-Shirts became more popular at the Linux Symposim over the years?

Comment: Maybe the teenagers of 1999 simply grew up.  Should compare this with the age statistics of the Linux Symposium attendees and t-shirt size statistics as a function of age.

Comment: I would also point out that, working in the athletic apparel business, I've seen the size of t-shirts change. In the last 5 years, there has been a push for slimmer fitting shirts, which has almost made a medium the size a small used to be. Granted, that was after 2008, but when looking at data, it would be good to keep in mind that 1999 small is not necessarily the same size as 2008 small.